# fill the slices with different colors on a pie chart

Tags: python, graph, reportlab

I have a pie chart with 6 slices, and I am looking forward to change the default colors that appear in the pie chart.
As far as I found , using the `.fillColor` I can change the color of a slice.

```
pie_chart = Drawing(200, 200)
pc = Pie()
pc.x = 65
pc.y = 15
pc.width = 150
pc.height = 150
pc.data = [65,13,12,9,1]
pc.labels = ['Name','Another','Yet Another','Test','Stack','Flow')

We can change the color of a slice using:
pc.slices[1].fillColor=red
```

However I am looking forward to change the color of all 6 slices and therefore I tried:

```
colores=[red,brown,violet,yellow,green,pink]
pc.slices.fillColors=colores
```

And it outputs the error:

```
AttributeError: Illegal attribute 'fillColors' in class WedgeProperties
```

My question is : How can I change the color of each slice in a single line of code? Is there any property to do so?

Comment: Have you looked at [the documentation](https://www.reportlab.com/snippets/1/)? The example there specifically includes this.

Comment: If you can only set one color at a time, use a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no attribute `fillColors`: it's singular, `fillColor`; you can't simply change the name and expect the parser to figure out what you mean.

As TemporalWolf already led you toward, the documentation shows how to do this with a loop.  In your case, something like:

```
for index, color in enumerate(colores):
    pc.slices[i].fillColor  = colores[i]
```

This assumes that you have `len(colores)` slices in your chart.

Comment: Would it not be safer to iterate over the `slices` instead? And use a `%` for the color list. Then you remove the need to have exactly as many (or less!) colors as there are slices.